# Rails + Devise - Session Controller explaination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am playing around with Devise in a project, and am just trying to better understand how it all works.  The Sessions controller in particular is doing a few things that I don't understand:

```
class Devise::SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # What benefit is this providing over just "resource_class.new"?
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    # What is "serialize_options" doing in the responder?
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
  ...

  protected
  ...

  def serialize_options(resource)
    methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
    methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
    methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
    { :methods => methods, :only => [:password] }
  end

  def sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
  end
end
```

I assume that these methods are adding some sort of security.  I'd just like to know what exactly they are protecting against.

Comment: For the first comment, are you asking about the `self.resource = ` part or the `(sign_in_params)` part? For the second comment, do you mean "what is `serialize_options` doing?" or "why is `serialize_options` being passed to the responder?"

Comment: I'm asking about the (sign_in_params) part (why are we sanitizing a new User object instead of just using User.new? And what does "sanitize" mean?), and then asking what serialize_options is doing and why.

Basically, I can replicate the same functionality from a BDD perspective by skipping both of these methods entirely, which leads me to believe that the value is in some sort of security that they are providing which I just don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The implementation of `devise_parameter_sanitizer`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/9281ac39588c768a48197a3f5c283f07d40bc593/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L83-L92) is creating a [ParameterSanitizer](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb) instance. I often find looking at tests to be helpful in understanding the purpose of code; and [this test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/parameter_sanitizer_test.rb#L36-L39) I think illustrates it best-- since you're creating a new user, you don't want to allow users to assign any value they want to any parameter they want, so `sanitize` means "strip out any attributes other than the ones we need for this action". If this wasn't here, and you had a `role` attribute, a user could send a specially-crafted POST request to make themselves an admin when signing up for your site. So this protects against what's called, in the general case, a [mass assignment vulnerability](http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment-revised?view=asciicast). [Rails 3 and Rails 4 protect against this in different ways](http://blog.sensible.io/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html) but the protections can still be turned off, and I'm guessing Devise is trying to set some good-practice defaults.

The `serialize_options` method is creating a hash of options to support rendering to XML or JSON. I found this out by looking at [the implementation of `responds_with`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L328), which calls `extract_options!` which uses the last argument as options if the last argument is a `Hash`. The documentation for `responds_with` says "All options given to #respond_with are sent to the underlying responder", so I looked at [`ActionController::Responder`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb), whose documentation explains the process it takes to look for a template that matches the format, then if that isn't found, calling `to_#{format}`, then calling `to_format`. There's a view for HTML, and `ActiveRecord` objects respond to `to_xml` and `to_json`. Those methods [use those options](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/xml.rb#L196-L199):

```
The <tt>:only</tt> and <tt>:except</tt> options can be used to limit the
attributes included, and work similar to the +attributes+ method.

To include the result of some method calls on the model use <tt>:methods</tt>.
```

So this keeps you from exposing more information than you might want to if someone uses the XML or JSON format.